# Docker build hangs indefinitely on windows 10

Tags: docker

When i run `docker build -t student-app-client .` to build the docker image nothings happens for long time.
Docker file is fine and it's working fine on Linux

**docker version** : 19.03.8

**Windows version** : Windows 10 pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that during docker build, docker was reading all files in the root directory folder which had lot of files.

I added all these files in `.dockerignore`. After this build completed with in minute.

Sample `.dockerignore` file

```
/node_modules/
/build/
```